# How to fetch the input values by importing an xslt into another xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have imported "Codelist.xsl" file in my another xslt and trying to call the template based upon the codes. In the imported file it contains list of code values. the input contains the codes. I'm not able to execute xslt based upon the input request. My xslt will be as below:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version"1.0">
<xsl:import href="local:///CodeList.xsl"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="AccountType1">
                                <xsl:call-template name="AccountType">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="AAccountType" select="$EmpAccountType"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable> 
          <xsl:variable name="EmpAccountType" select="Employee/EmployeeType/Type/Account/EmpAccountType"/>
                          <Accounttype>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$AccountType1"/>
                          </Accounttype>    
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My imported file contains:

```
<xsl:template name="AccountType">
        <xsl:param name="AAccountType"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$AAccountType='01'">A</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$AAccountType='02'">B</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$AAccountType='03'">C</xsl:when>            
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My input will be like:

```
<Employee>
<EmployeeType>
<Type>
<Account>
<EmpAccountType>02</EmpAccountType>
</Account>
</Type>
</EmployeeType>
</Employee>
```

But I'm not able to fetch the value from input. Can someone correct me where am I going wrong in my xslt ?

Comment: Post minimal but complete samples to allow anyone to reproduce the problem; that first snippet does not show any context nor any binding for the variable `$EmpAccountType` it references so it is rather pointless to expect us to tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have pasted the rest of the code now. I have made my code short in length to keep it simple.

Comment: Do you get any error message? You would need to declare the variable before referencing it.

Comment: `<xsl:import href="local:///CodeList.xsl"/>` also looks a bit unusual as a URI.

Comment: I'm receiving empty response. where my expected output should be <EmpAccountType>B</EmpAccountType>

Comment: Does the template work if you embed it directly into the main stylesheet? Then look into the `xsl:import`, that URI `local:///CodeList.xsl` looks rather odd to me, but there also settings where import or includes don't work. So check whether any import at all works, we can't do that for you and you haven't given any indication how you run XSLT.

Comment: use <xsl:include href="local:///CodeList.xsl"/> , not <xsl:import href="local:///CodeList.xsl"/>

Comment: Thankyou. It worked.